# Can not import pygst under windows 7 (32bit)

Tags: python, windows-7, gstreamer

I am using windows 7 (32bit) and python 2.7.3.

For gstreamer, I installed:

- GStreamer-WinBuilds-LGPL-x86-Beta04-0.10.7
- GStreamer-WinBuilds-SDK-LGPL-x86-Beta04-0.10.7

However, I get the following error:

```
ImportError: No module named pygst
```

And I was confused with previous similar questions and answers, anyway I can't fix this by copy files or rename dlls.

Answer (score 0):

`python-gst0.10` is only in `extras-devel` right now. You have to add this repository to your `/etc/apt/sources.list`:

> http://repository.maemo.org/extras-devel

This should work. If it doesn't add a comment :)

Answer (score 0):

OK. I tested these on win xp with python 2.7. It's absolutely OK!
Then I check again in win 7, after my installing of GStreamer. Python could not import pygsst, however as there is already PYTHONPATH for gstreamer. I just checked this enviroment variables in system variables, and I found python can import pygst ... Maybe it is the problem of WIN7, system permissions or delay? Have no idea...